# How to delete old styles of django

Tags: django

I have multiple projects of django running on my PC for learning.
When I open second project, it is still loading the styles of first project.
How to clear this?

Comment: try to hard refresh browser window sometime it loads cache

Answer (score 1):

try deleting all cache files and restart your browser.

Comment: It is getting same output on other browser also, newly installed one

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome open Developer tools and under network tab check "Disable Cache". This will force browser to request new assets.